# Generate 8.3 filenames with standard library

Tags: python, filesystems

I would like to generate an 8.3 filename (as used on DOS/FAT) without the modules `win32api` or `ctypes` (neither works with my configuration).

Currently, the code is this:

```py
def short_names(names):
    names2 = []
    for i in names:
        append_tilde = True
        
        b = set(".\"/\\[]:;=, ") # ."/\[]:;=,[space] (forbidden chars)
        old = i
        
        for char in b:
            i = i.replace(char, "")
        
        if i == old: append_tilde = False
        
        name_parts = i.split(sep=".")
        name = ''.join(name_parts[0:len(name_parts)-1])
        extension = name_parts[-1][0:3]
        
        if len(name) > 6:
            name = name[0:6]
            append_tilde = True
        
        if append_tilde:
            for j in range(1,10):
                if name.upper()+"~"+str(j) not in names2:
                    names2.append(name.upper() + "~" + str(j))
                    break
                    
        
    return names2
```

But it returns the "~1" part only, not the 6-character part plus "~1".

For the example input:

`["Program Files", "ProgramData", "Programme", "Documents and Settings", "Dokumente und Einstellungen"]`
it returns
`['~1', '~2', '~3']`

Intended return value:

`["PROGRA~1", "PROGRA~2", "PROGRA~3", "DOCUME~1", "DOKUME~1"]`

Python version: `Python 3.10.1 (v3.10.1:2cd268a3a9, Dec  6 2021, 14:28:59) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin`

Comment: Given that none of your test data has extensions, what do you think will be the result of your extension removing code?

Comment: @MarkRansom the extensions will be processed separately, that is not the subject.

Comment: It is *exactly* the subject, trace your code.

Comment: Let me be more direct: what will `name` contain if there isn't an extension?

Comment: At different times, it is intended to contain `Progra`, `Progra`, `Progra`, `Docume`, and `Dokume`. However, that isn't happening...

Comment: Exactly, that's not happening.  Can you see the bug in your code now?

Comment: There is a bug, however, it is "hidden" in code and I see no easy way to correct it. `name = ''.join(name_parts[0:len(name_parts)-1])` should have outputted the name, right? Or, is it something else?

Comment: Yes that is the place. You need to make it conditional so it does something different when there's no extension.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242440/discussion-between-oliver-and-mark-ransom).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way you try to split a filename into a base part and an extension.

If you call `split('.')` on a string that doesn't have a `.` in it, you get back a list with a single element - your original string.  This means that `name_parts[0:len(name_parts)-1]` is the same as `name_parts[0:0]` which is an empty list.  You're setting `name` to an empty string, while `extension` is set to the first 3 characters of the entire file name.

You need to detect the case where there was no `.` in the filename and treat it differently.

```
    name_parts = i.split(sep=".")
    if len(name_parts) <= 1:
        name = i
        extension = ''
    else:
        name = ''.join(name_parts[0:len(name_parts)-1])
        extension = name_parts[-1][0:3]
```

P.S. Python has some facilities to make this easier.  Check out [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) or [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib).